# tidyverse and some R version 4.2.0 packages not working on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, ubuntu-22.04

Although I try to install, this package and others do not work. How to proceed properly?

```
install.packages("tidyverse", dependencies = T)
```

> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
> ERROR: dependency ‘ggplot2’ is not available for package ‘tidyverse’
> removing ‘/home/vitor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2/tidyverse’
> Warning in install.packages :
> installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/RtmpMfKJxK/downloaded_packages’

Comment: What happens when you do `install.packages("ggplot2")`?

Comment: 22.04 is still pretty new at a month old

Comment: There are TWO sets of differences. First, for R, it is between _from source_ installation (default on Linux) and _binary_.  Second, you can install from R (as you tried) or via `apt` and friends: `sudo apt install r-cran-ggplot2` as the package is part of Ubuntu. 
 Now there is a contributed repo -- see the detailed [README.md at CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), read it carefully including the section on 5000k add-on packages and maybe come to the r-sig-debian list.  A lot to grok, many options.

Comment: @qwr That is an irrelevant comment as `ggplot` has been part of Ubuntu as `r-cran-ggplot2` for many years and hence been part of _every_ release for several cycles.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Ill try via apt, not Just with tidyverse packages but with others like tseries.

Comment: It's not about unbuntu or ggplot2 exclusively, it's lots of packages at least on Centos.   E.g. xml2.